# Remove this string "\r" inside a column from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe with more than 40k rows. Before I deleted all the empty emails and incorrect emails using a regex, but yer there are some emails that has this `\r` string and the end of the domain and also exists in some of it one space.

```
                             email                   name  last_name
50052       juancitopues@gmail.com  \r        JUAN ANDRES     DAVILA
50053       marcosjhon27@gmail.com\r     MARCOS JHONNATAN   ESQUIVES
```

I tried using replace but I was not capable of remove that strings `\r`

```
df_final['email'] = df_final['email'].str.replace('\r', '')
df_final['email'] = df_final['email'].str.replace(' \r', '')
```

Any idea I will appreciate guys, thanks so much.

Comment: does not work bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try escaping `\`:

via `replace()`+`strip()`:

```
df['email']=df['email'].replace(r'\\r','',regex=True).str.strip()
```

OR

via `rstrip()`+`strip()`:

```
df['email']=df['email'].str.rstrip("\\r").str.strip()
```